# content block https from http

Tags: https

```
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');

function themename_customize_register($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_section('ignite_custom_logo', array(
        'title' => 'Logo',
        'description' => 'Display a custom logo?',
        'priority' => 25
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('custom_logo', array(
        'default' => ''
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'custom_logo', array(
        'label' => 'Custom logo',
        'section' => 'ignite_custom_logo',
        'settings' => 'custom_logo'
    )));

}
```

I followed the above snippets but I have faced some issues. if I add the image from customizing it returns warning in console section.

this is error

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dev-' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://dev-'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

can u please explain why this happened to me?

Comment: Nothing in this code would cause that issue. What code are you using to output the logo in the template?

Comment: <a  class="white-logo"  href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" id="site-logo" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                    </a>


This is what i have used for rendering the logo in frontend via customise settings

Comment: What is m1_logo? Your question says custom_logo.

Comment: actually, I renamed the value custom_logo to m1_logo.